# Cannot call unknown function

Tags: javascript, emscripten

I'm trying to compile a medium-size existing code base with emscripten. Everything currently compiles, but when I try to call it from javascript I'm getting the error:

> Assertion failed: Cannot call unknown function InitHOG (perhaps LLVM optimizations or closure removed it?)

I've declared this as:

```
extern "C" {

void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE InitHOG()
{ ... }

}
```

I'm linking the function from javascript with:

```
InitHog = Module.cwrap('InitHOG', 'void', []);
```

My code base is being compiled into libraries; the function call into the library is in my guihtml library, where the final linking command is:

> emcc  -o ../../../../html/debug/bidirnecessary.js  ../../../../objs_html/bidirnecessary.js/debug/demos/bidirnecessary/Driver.o  -lenvironments -lmapalgorithms -lalgorithms -lgraphalgorithms -lgraph -lutils -lguihtml -L../../../../html/debug -Lapps/libs -Ldemos/libs -lpthread -g

Any ideas on why it can't find my function from javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE` keyword works when you are compiling a single file to .js output, it **doesn't work** in my makefile system where I compile individual files, use `emar` to make a library, and then link everything together at the end.

Instead, you need to use the `-s` directive to specify which functions you want to export. So, something like this works.

> emcc -o ../../../../html/debug/bidirnecessary.js ../../../../objs_html/bidirnecessary.js/debug/demos/bidirnecessary/Driver.o -lenvironments -lmapalgorithms -lalgorithms -lgraphalgorithms -lgraph -lutils -lguihtml -lgui -L../../../../html/debug -Lapps/libs -Ldemos/libs -lpthread -g -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_InitHOG', '_DoFrame', '_MouseEvent']"